# Query on MySql by date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my database, to register apartment rentals, this is a summary of the structure:

```
+--------------------+
|        rental      |
|--------------------|
|  id (int)          |
|  date_init (date)  |
|  date_end  (date)  |
|  amount    (double)|
+--------------------+
```

So I would like to get all the records that are valid for example all this year, this would be the range of dates `2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31`. This should not only include records that begin and end in this year, but also those that began in 2018 and end in 2020 for example. since they would be valid all this year too, so how could I do this?

**edit**

sorry if I express myself badly, I must obtain all the records that are valid within my date range, as an example, mention not only those records that begin and end within the date range, but also those that begin long before and end within the range or a long time later, since they would be in effect, I hope you have expressed myself well

Comment: Wouldn't this do the trick ?  `WHERE YEAR(date_init) <= 2019 AND YEAR(date_end) => 2019` or am I being to simplistic

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes, this is exactly how I see it. Only that I don't invoke a function on `date_init` and `date_end` in my answer, so the DBMS is more likely to use an index, if such exists.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite simple actually. You want the start be in or before 2019 and the end in or after 2019.

```
select *
from rental
where date_init < date '2020-01-01'
and date_end >= date '2019-01-01'
order by id;
```

Comment: what about those records where start and end are both in the 2019 year?

Comment: @LelioFaieta . . . The OP is not looking for those records.

Comment: And what happens if my registration has `date_init 2018-10-02` and as `date_end 2019-05-02`, it was valid a couple of months this year but it would not enter your query

Comment: _This should not only include records that begin and end in this year_ I assume that he is not writing it properly in this sentence or in the beginning of the question

Comment: _And what happens if my registration has date_init 2018-10-02 and as date_end 2019-05-02_ this is another comment from OP. End date is before 2019-12-31

Comment: @max: Why do you think my query doesn't select `date_init 2018-10-02` and `date_end 2019-05-02`? `2018-10-02` is `< date '2020-01-01'` and `2019-05-02` is `>= date '2019-01-01'`. Have you even tried my query?

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: "what about those records where start and end are both in the 2019 year?" Well, as you see from my query, I select them. Do you think for some reason that I shouldn't?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I see it now... my bad!